# Calling React JS from jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, reactjs

I am new to React, and I'm making a webpage to show a list of items.

I have this React Code in a file called admins.js:

```
 //more code

    var AdminsBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {adminsList: []};
    },
    setAdminsArray: function(data) {
        this.setState({adminsList: data});
    },
    render: function() {

        return (
            <div>
                <AdminsContentBox adminsList={this.state.adminsList}/>
            </div>
        );
    }});

    var AdminsBoxRender = ReactDOM.render(
        <AdminsBox />,
        document.getElementById('adminsContent')
    );
```

And in the file index.jsp:

```
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" />
        <script src="react.js"></script>
        <script src="react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="browser.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="marked.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="material.indigo-blue.min.css">

        <script type="text/babel" src="admins.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'myUrlServlet',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: "function=getAdmins",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                        AdminsBoxRender.setAdminsArray(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>


 <body>
        <div id="adminsContent"></div>
    </body>
```

The error I get is AdminsBoxRender is not defined.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the proper way to fetch data for your component, you should fetch it in `componentDidMount()`

```
var AdminsBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {adminsList: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
         $.ajax({
                url: 'myUrlServlet',
                type: 'POST',
                data: "function=getAdmins",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    this.setState({adminsList: data});
                }
            });
    },
    setAdminsArray: function(data) {
        this.setState({adminsList: data});
    },
    render: function() {

        return (
            <div>
                <AdminsContentBox adminsList={this.state.adminsList}/>
            </div>
        );
}});


window.AdminsBoxRender = ReactDOM.render(
    <AdminsBox />,
    document.getElementById('adminsContent')
);
```

You should keep the stuff related to React "inside" React.

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. With the method "componenDidMount" inside the react component, I still get the same error. From your last sentece, I supposed that I cannot access the component outside react?

Comment: You can access from outside, but it's not "safe" since the component may not be rendered yet. You can attach the rendered component to the window object, that way you'll be sure you can access to it anywhere.

Comment: Attaching the rendered component to the window object has worked well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach would fall under the heading of "fighting the framework".

I would recommend going with QoP's *first* recommendation rather than attaching the component to the window object.